# How to spawn collectables or pickups in patterns and at random positions using Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am Making a 2d endless runner using Phaser 3 and I need to spawn coins and other pickups in random positions and also in different patterns such as diamond shape, square,...
I don't really have much code and I do not know how to go about it. I would gladly appreciate any help in any way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your code-structure, but I would use the builtin function `Phaser.Math.Between`, to generate random positions/numbers ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Math.html#.Between__anchor)).

(**Sidenote:** The first examples are made for **arcade** physics, the final one with is made for **matter.js** )

**Here is a very simple approach:**

In code:

- The interval in which coins are spawned is random
  `setTimeout(_ => this.loadCoins(coins), Phaser.Math.Between(2500, 3000));`
- The position of the pickup is random
  `let yCoord = Phaser.Math.Between(20, 180);`
  `let xCord = 400 + Phaser.Math.Between(0, 100);`
- The pickup type is random
  `let coinType = Phaser.Math.Between(0, 2);`
- and te amount of coins to spawn
  `let coinsToSpawn = Phaser.Math.Between(1, 5);`

```js
class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
      super({ key: 'GameScene' });
    }
    
    loadCoins(coins){
       let coin;
       
       // Generate random amount of coins each time
       let coinsToSpawn = Phaser.Math.Between(1, 5);
       
       for(let i = 0; i < coinsToSpawn; i++){
         
          // Get Random y position (x is always bigger than the scene width)
          let yCoord = Phaser.Math.Between(20, 180);
          let xCord = 400 + Phaser.Math.Between(0, 100);

          // Randomly generate types
          let coinType = Phaser.Math.Between(0, 2);
          
          switch(coinType){
            case 0:
              coin = this.add.rectangle(xCord, yCoord, 15, 15, 0xFFFF00);
              break;
            case 1:
              coin = this.add.circle(xCord, yCoord, 7, 0xFF0000);
              break;
            case 2:
              coin = this.add.star(xCord, yCoord, 5, 5, 15, 0x00FF00);
              break;
          }
       
            coin = this.physics.add.existing(coin);
            coins.add(coin);
        }  
        coins.setVelocityX(-100); 
        
        // Start next Coin loading randomly in 2.5 - 3 Seconds
        setTimeout(_ => this.loadCoins(coins), Phaser.Math.Between(2500, 3000)); 
    }
    
    create() {
       
        this.player = this.add.rectangle(200, 100, 20, 20, 0xffffff);
        this.physics.add.existing(this.player);

        //Add World Physics
        this.physics.world.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 200);
        this.player.body.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
        this.player.body.setImmovable(true);

        let coins = this.physics.add.group({immovable: true, allowGravity: false});
        
        
        this.loadCoins(coins);
        
        this.physics.add.collider(this.player, coins, 
          (player, coin) => { 
            coin.destroy();
        });
  }
}

const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    scene: [ GameScene ],
    physics: {
       default: 'arcade',
    }
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

**Update (create shapes with coins):**

-> Check out some cool builtin functions in the `Phaser.Actions` Namespace ([like to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Actions.html#.PlaceOnCircle__anchor)).
like _(to name a few)):

- `Phaser.Actions.PlaceOnCircle`
- `Phaser.Actions.PlaceOnLine`
- `Phaser.Actions.PlaceOnTriangle`
- ...

***Disclaimer:** This code is not optimal is just created like this to proof the point.*

**UPDATE for spawning:**

***Sidenotes:***

1. the spawn has to be trigger, so I use `setInterval`, but you can use events, user input, or simply in the `update` function, or ...
2. the cleanup and the saving of the groups could be handled better, but it's a demo.

```js
class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super({ key: 'GameScene' });

        //keep reference to the groups
        this.coinGroups = [];
    }
    
    spawnCoins(){

       let coins = this.physics.add.group({immovable: true, allowGravity: false});
        
       var circle = new Phaser.Geom.Circle(440, 80, 40);
       for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            let coin = this.add.circle(0, 0, 8, 0xFFFF00);
            coin = this.physics.add.existing(coin);
            coins.add(coin);
        }  
        coins.setVelocityX(-100); 

        this.coinGroups.push(coins);
        
        Phaser.Actions.PlaceOnCircle(coins.getChildren(), circle);
    }
    
    create() {
        this.add.text(10,10,'Spawing every 2sec')
            .setColor('#ffffff');

        // Spawing ever 2 Sec
        setInterval( _ => {
            this.spawnCoins();
        }, 2000);
    }

    update(){
        // Minor Cleanup
        for(let group of this.coinGroups){
            group.getChildren().forEach(child => {
                if(child.x < 0){
                    group.remove(child, true, true);
                }
            });
        }
        this.coinGroups = this.coinGroups.filter(group => group.length > 0 );  
    }
}

const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    scene: [ GameScene ],
    physics: {
       default: 'arcade',
    }
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

**Mini demo with *matter.js*:**

```js
class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super({ key: 'GameScene' });
        //keep reference to the groups
        this.coinGroups = [];
    }
    
    spawnCoins(){

       // standart Phaser Group
       let coins = this.add.group();
        
       var circle = new Phaser.Geom.Circle(440, 80, 40);
       for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            let coin = this.matter.add.image(50, 50, 'coin').setOrigin(.5);
            coin.setIgnoreGravity(true);
            coin.setVelocityX(-3); 
            coin.setFrictionAir(0);
            coins.add(coin);
        }  

        this.coinGroups.push(coins);
        
        Phaser.Actions.PlaceOnCircle(
            coins.getChildren(), circle);
    }
    
    create() {
         this.add.text(10, 10, 'Coins spawned every second')
         .setOrigin(0)
         .setColor('#ffffff');
         
         // Just creating a texture/image for matter
         let g = this.make.graphics({x: 0, y: 0, add: false});
         g.fillStyle(0xffff00);
         g.fillCircle(7, 7, 7);
         g.generateTexture('coin', 14, 14);
          
          setInterval( _ => this.spawnCoins(), 1000);
    }

    update(){
      // Clean Up       
        for(let group of this.coinGroups){
            group.getChildren().forEach(child => {
                if(child.x < 0){
                    group.remove(child, true, true);
                }
            });
        }
       
        this.coinGroups = this.coinGroups.filter(group => group.getChildren().length > 0);
    }
}

const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    scene: [ GameScene ],
     physics: {
        default: 'matter'
    },
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: The random spawning is alright but to make the coins to individually form position at the x,y points forming a zigzag, diamond shapes.I am thinking of  Creating the coin group, then function Coin(x, y) {

  //Run the sprite code
  Phaser.Sprite.call(this, scene, x, y, 'coin');

  //Add coin to the game
  this.coinGroup.add(this);} coinshape ={} coinshape.zigzag= function(x,y){coin1 = new Coin(x,y) and form a shape and I don't know how to do any of these I am only giving a suggestion @winner_joiner

Comment: I have been working on it and there is a problem is there a way for them to spawn continuously without setTimeout, because when the timeout calls the function it destroys the already created and so loops. I wanted it if it collides with world bounds destroy and I also wanted many to keep on spawning regardless of collision. I hope you understand. Thanks for the earlier responses.

Comment: @AceEnyioko yes there is, the `setTimeout` is only for showcasing the concept. writing the whole actual spawning script would be much longer/complicated. And I try to answer with the least code possible not to confuse. I will update the second example to spawn _"better"_.

Comment: It's a very good way and code strategy, I've mingled my code with yours it works. I'm having a little problem my matter physics player is not colliding  with arcade physics coins. I know is not part of my question but still if you can, help. Thanks alot again.

Comment: @AceEnyioko well mixing physics-engines is not really the best option, if they should collide. I personally would select one and do everything with that specific engine. the easy way is **arcade**, but **matter** should also be possible.

Comment: @AceEnyioko I added a mini _matter_ demo, it is not complete, but I hope this helps you on your journey

Comment: Awesome I'll use this, it will surely help out, I'm very grateful